# What is the appropriate word to describe society's toughest problem?

Tags: single-word-requests, sociolinguistics

I am looking for an adjective to use in the following context:

> I was pondering on ways of addressing society's most ______ issues.

Comment: essential, crucial, capital.

Comment: How about *pertinent*?

Comment: Vital, critical

Comment: stubborn, intractable, pressing

Comment: The word "Ills" seems to come up quite regularly.

Comment: What context? What are you trying to say? We can't tell from a blank!

Comment: I don't see a problem with "society's toughest issues".

Comment: Normally "pressing" would be used in that context, though that implies the "urgent-important" quadrant, vs simply "important".

Comment: "Intractable" is a very good suggestion, ab2. But I see that you aren't trying to scoop up easy points by formally answering this question.

Comment: [Here's the link to a relevant Meta question.](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2653/why-are-answers-being-posted-in-the-comments-on-the-question)

Answer (score 10):

> I was pondering on ways of addressing society's most ***pressing*** issues.

Comment: "Pressing" suggests urgency and perhaps even importance, but not necessarily difficulty.  Difficulty is only secondarily implied by the contextual implication that the problem has not *yet* been solved, but there may be other reasons for this (e.g. the pressing issue is recovery from a disaster that just happened recently).

Comment: It's a one liner, but it's a good suggestion. If I had answered this question I would have linked the word to an online dictionary, or cited similar examples. But sometimes, a one liner is all the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 5):

> I was pondering on ways of addressing society's most ***challenging*** issues.

(*Toughest* instead of *most challenging* also works.)

Another term that may fit what you are looking for is "***wicked***," as in "*[wicked problems](http://medlibrary.org/medwiki/Wicked_problem)*," a term largely attributed to Rittel & Webber's 1973 paper "[Dilemmas in a General Theory of Planning](http://www.metu.edu.tr/~baykan/arch467/Rittel+Webber+Dilemmas.pdf)."  The term recently got a bunch of press coverage from its appearance in a [*Science* article](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/351/6268/32.full) contemplating how to solve such problems with large crowds of people.

---

*1: Rittel, H. W. J., & Webber, M. M. (1973). Dilemmas in a General Theory of Planning. Policy Sciences, 4, 155–169. http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01405730#page-1*

Comment: "Wicked" is generally used for largely pleasant intellectual challenges (like P = NP) rather than social problems that have real-life consequences.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm No, the original meaning is referring to social problems with real-life consequences.  The canonical example is urban planning.  Today, the most frequent example is probably climate change.  Also, there would be major real-life consequences if P=NP. See [Travelling Salesman](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1801123/) for a discussion about this latter point.

Answer (score 1):

> I was pondering on ways of addressing society's most **profound** issues.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the word "pernicious"?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. It is not encouraged to post an answer without any research/reference/link that can support it. Please edit your answer after taking the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visiting our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: What we're looking for at English Language & Usage, Colin, is answers that are self-contained, in that they provide an explanation or justification of why they are valid answers. You can make your answer much stronger by including a quotation (and if possible a link) to a reputable dictionary's definition of _pernicious_ that illustrates that word's suitability as a fill-in-the-blank word in the example the original poster presents.

Answer (score 0):

innate-is one solution. Most of us trying to make positive changes were born into what is.

Comment: The rest of these answers are just synonyms of *toughest*. This is actually somewhat profound.

Answer (score 0):

"Pressing" would equate to "most urgent" (as in pressed for time)

"Toughest" already works well but I guess to expand you have to know on what basis they are the toughest.

"challenging" = difficult to solve
"prevalent" = widespread
"distressing", "damaging", "worrying"

It really depends on the context you want to infer.
Perhaps you need to start by defining what the most xxx problems are, then you can search out an adjective for them.